# Separating a single string into two different strings in C

Tags: c, string

I take user input in `char name[20]` using `fgets` like this:

```
fgets(name,20,stdin);
```

The user enters two strings separated by white space like `John Smith`. What if I wanted to use `John` and `Smith` in two strings like `char name[20]` , `char surname[20]` or just compare `John` and `Smith` using `strcmp`?

I tried a lot, but I did not find any way to do this.

What are some ways to fix this kind of problem?

Comment: Read this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: `sscanf(name, "%19s %19s", fisrtname, surname);`,

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn [`char * strtok (char *restrict newstring, const char *restrict delimiters)`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) function in C uses to  splitting a string up into token separated by set of  delimiters.

You input string `John Smith` is separated by space (`' '`) char. You need to write a code something like below:

```
char *token;
token = strtok(name, " ");  // first name 
strcpy(fname, token);
token = strtok(NULL, " ");  // second name 
strcpy(lname, token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search for the blank within the string yourself - look up the strchr function for that. Then, use strncpy to copy the two parts in 2 different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) function to split strings.